# Choosing the port number at tcp client side while using iperf

Tags: networking, tcp, port

I am using iperf client and iperf server in TCP mode. (they are running on different Linux machines)

iperf has an option -p to choose the server port.

I want to be able to choose the client port, as in the source port of the TCP connection between iperf client and server. Currently Linux chooses a random source port at the iperf client side

I do not think it is possible using iperf (correct me if I am wrong), if not any other way to do it?

Thanks